# 14.04 LTS not recognizing all my RAM

Tags: 14.04, ram

I recently installed 32 Bit 14.04 on my old XP computer.  It seems to have installed without issues, however all of the RAM is not being recognized.  In the system info it says 2.4 GiB, I believe I have 1024 MB installed.

This is what I can tell you about my computer.
P4 2.6 GHz
Graphics 8656 x86/mmx/SSE2

Comment: 2.4 GiB > 1 GiB = 1024 MB. Something doesn't add up here. Your system information shows more RAM than you claim to have installed.

Comment: Could you add the output of this command: `free -h --mega`?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have 1024MB installed memory plus 1200MB or so swap.

Use `free -m` to see the memory and swap amount in megabytes or `free -h` for a "human readable" representation.

(Use `cat /proc/meminfo` to see complete details about memory )